# Dynamic TextView

Tags: iphone

I need to implemente a textview whose frame should be changed according to input string length. Can anyone help me out how to start the things off.. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the three20 framework. They have a class called TTTextView, which supports resizing:

http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_text_view.html

Comment: Try downloading the framework and playing around with it a bit then